# How to bind a gtk widget to a python variable or @property?

Tags: python, data-binding, gtk3

I would like to separate my model (property) from the view (gtk widget).

For example: my model has a "level" property.
I would like to bind the "level" to  `GtkScrollbar` and to a `GtkLabel` so that a change to the variable e.g. `self.level=5` will be reflected in the widgets and a change in the widgets will set the property.

This is common practice in many frameworks (WPF).

How to do this with python+gtk ?
or is there a library for doing this binding?

Comment: Please provide some minimal mock code to illustrate what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Official [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/GBinding.html) provides exhaustive answer on bindings.

What you need exactly is [bind_property_full](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#GObject-2.0/classes/Object.html#GObject.Object.bind_property_full) method with custom function for transformation from GtkScrollbar's value (which is a number) to GtkLabel's string.

Comment: @user1656671 Not really. There is another approach, which involves more code. As a `GtkRange`'s subclass `GtkScrollbar` emits `"value-changed"` signal when user moves the slider. You can connect to this signal and update your label value. Moreover, you can use the power of [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) to update both scrollbar and label when somebody updates `self.level`. However, you must understand, that GTK functions should only be called from main loop.

Comment: Damn, looks like I should've read the question more careful. Well, if your model _knows_ about Label and Scrollbar, just update your setter and connect to said signal.

Comment: The idea is that my model would not know abut the controls, or at least would not have to know..
The best would be to define a model in terms of data types and bind as simply as possible. For example binding by looking up keys in glade files - as can be done with events.